# How to convert UTC to datetime in Excel

Tags: excel

I am  trying to convert UTC to datetime in EXCEL SHEET.

Below is the input

```
2020-04-10T22:15:40.5577209Z
```

So far to convert I have put below formula

`=(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"T"," "))`

This gives me output as

```
2020-04-10 22:15:40.5577209Z
```

Now I need to trim the `.5577209Z` part.

Final output should be

`2020-04-10 22:15:40`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Assuming it's a string. You could do simple string manipulation to remove the last bit.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought it was a python question haha. For excel, you can get the substring to the left of the period, as it only occurs once in the cell. Replace the "-" with a "." and the cell accordingly. See this example "=LEFT(B10,SEARCH("-", B10)-1)" from https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3639-excel-extract-part-of-string.html#char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result you want would be produced with a formula like this one. (The original string is in A2)

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT((SUBSTITUTE(A2,"T"," ")),18))+ TIMEVALUE(LEFT((SUBSTITUTE(A2,"T"," ")),18))
```

The formula takes the first 18 characters of the received string. If you are sure that there are no letters in the next couple of digits you could extend this to 20 or more and get a better rounding of the seconds.

Another approach would be to work around the offending "T".

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,12,8))
```

Again the final 8 in the formula could be extended for better rounding of seconds. Or, if it's always a "Z" it could simply be removed like you already removed the "T".

Either solution gives you a true Date/Time value - a 5-digit number with lots of decimals. This you  convert into a legible date by means of the cell format. Apply a custom format like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`